# What is the canonical representation of a point in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm going to be doing some geometric calculations involving 2-D and 3D points using numpy.

What is the canonical representation of a 2-D or 3-D point?  Please assume minimal familiarity with numpy, data shapes, etc.

Comment: Is this a question you have, or a set up to propose a new canonical? It's hard to tell with "canonical" in the title and a high rep user.

Comment: `scipy.spatial` and `scipy.interpolate` functions take arrays of 'points', but `numpy` itself doesn't formally use the concept of 'point'.  Functions like `meshgrid` can make a n-d coordinate grid from 1-d arrays.

Comment: It's a question I have, I don't know much about numpy etc.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Represent them in your source code as tuples or lists, e.g. `(1, 0)` or `[1, 0, 1]`.

As per this example from [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean.html):

```
>>> from scipy.spatial import distance
>>> distance.euclidean([1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0])
1.4142135623730951
```

Comment: That's a great question.  [1,0,0] was the clue.  As a rank beginner, I didn't know if I  was looking for a Point() class, some magic syntax, etc.,   I was looking for some kind of Point() class or somesuch;  It turns out either a list or tuple is what is commonly used.  In this, you might be at a disadvantage because of your expertise, since the point representation was so embedded in your brain it didn't stand out as the thing which was confusing to a total beginner such as myself.

Comment: @Adriaan, ahh, I see you've added a bounty which probably accounts for your interest.  Note that I had originally added my observation (which was actually what I found that allowed me to carry forward) to Andras' excellent writeup.  But note that most of his writeup actually answers his own question: "A much better question is how to represent collections of points in Cartesian space. ".  The history reveals that he deleted my tldr, so I added it as a separate answer.  I respect his wishes in that; if the answer were to include the quick clue that I had needed, I would reaccept his answer.

Comment: @Adriann, and I should say, that if you can convince Andras to restore the tldr at the top (which answered my simple-minded question!) I would be happy to re-select his answer and delete mine.  And I should also thank you for being concerned enough to ask the question!

Comment: That's what "as per" means, but I'm happy to clarify if you think that's better.  For simple minds such as myself "row-wise" tends to confuse things by answering questions I'm not thinking about.  Think of me as your basic simpleton trying to figure out how to print hello world and not needing an explanation of devices, drivers, etc.

Answer (score 24):

The representation of a single point in Cartesian space is somewhat trivial. You could even use flat tuples or lists to represent them and matrix operations would still work, but if you want to add or scale them (which is fundamentally what [linear spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) are for) you have to use arrays. I don't see a reason why not to use a 1d array with shape `(d,)` in `d` dimensions: you can use those both as column and row vectors on either side of a matrix using the `@` matmul operator:

```
import numpy as np 

rot90 = np.array([[0, -1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]])  # rotate 90 degrees around z
inp = np.array([1, 0, 0])  # x 

# rotate: 
inp_rot = rot90 @ inp  # y 
# inverse transform: 
inp_invrot = inp @ rot90  # -y
```

A much better question is how to represent *collections* of points in Cartesian space. If you have `N` points you will probably want to use a 2d array. But which shape should it be, `(N, d)` or `(d, N)`? The answer depends on your use case but without further input you'll want to choose `(N, d)`.

Arrays in numpy are "C-contiguous" by default, which is also called row-major memory layout. This means that on creation an array occupies a contiguous block of memory by default, and items are laid out in memory row after row, with these indices as an example:

```
>>> np.arange(2*3).reshape(2, 3)
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

One of the reasons we use numpy is that a contiguous block of memory for a given type occupies much less space than a native python container of the same size, at least for large datasets. The other reason is that we can use vectorized operations that work on slices of the input "simultaneously". The quotes are there because fundamentally the hands of the CPU are bound, but it turns out that you can achieve quite some speedup by making good use of CPU caches. And this is where memory layout comes into play: by using operations on an array that access elements close in memory you have a higher chance of making use of caching, and the reduced communication between RAM and CPU will lead to shorter runtimes.

The problem is not trivial, because vectorizing along larger non-contiguous dimensions might end up faster than vectorizing along smaller contiguous ones. However, without any additional information it's a good rule of thumb to put those dimensions last where you are likely to perform vectorized operations and reductions such as `.mean()` or `.sum()`. In case of `N` points in `d`-dimensional space it's quite likely that you will want to handle each point separately. Loops in matrix multiplications and things like scalar products and vector norms will all want you to work with one component after the other for a given point.

This is why you will see numpy and scipy functions usually assume arrays of shape `(N, d)`: the inner dimension is second and the "batch" index is first. Consider for example [`numpy.linalg.eig`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html):

```
Parameters: 

a : (…, M, M) array

    Matrices for which the eigenvalues and right eigenvectors will be computed

Returns:    

w : (…, M) array

    The eigenvalues, each repeated according to its multiplicity. The eigenvalues
    are not necessarily ordered. The resulting array will be of complex type,
    unless the imaginary part is zero in which case it will be cast to a real
    type. When a is real the resulting eigenvalues will be real (0 imaginary
    part) or occur in conjugate pairs

[...]
```

It treats multidimensional arrays as batches of matrices, where the last two indices correspond to the Cartesian indices. Similarly the returned eigenvalues and eigenvectors have batch indices first and vector space indices last.

A more direct example is [`scipy.spatial.distance.pdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) which computes the distance between pairs of points in a collection:

```
Parameters

    X : ndarray
        An m by n array of m original observations in an n-dimensional space.

[...]
```

Again you can see the convention that Cartesian indices are last. The same goes for [`scipy.interpolate.griddata`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html) and probably a bunch of other functions.

So if you have a good reason to use either representation: do that. But if you don't have a good indicator (such as the results of profiling both representations) you should stick with the "batch of vectors/matrices" approach usually employed by numpy and scipy (shape `(N, d)`), because you might even end up using some of these functions, for which your representation will then be native.